# Approximation scheme for integrating small differentials?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, perturbation-theory, approximate-integration

Let's say I have some differential $dy/dt$. I want to calculate the definite integral over some interval $t = 0-T$ i.e.

$$ y(T) = \int_0^{T} \frac{dy}{dt} dt$$

**My question is** if $dy/dt$ is very small such that $dy/dt << T$ is there some approximation scheme (perturbative or otherwise) that I can use for calculating $y(T)$?

Thanks in advance

**Some extra background:**

I have an equation for $dy/dt$ that I have lifted from a paper that described the evolution of some quantity over time. I could integrate this numerically, but I would also like an analytical expression. $dy/dt$ is very small and I want to integrate for a time $T$ which is very large.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the integrand is small for an approximation to work; you need to bound its variation between $0$ and $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem likely that any good estimation system should exist. The fact that $\frac {dy}{dt}$ is very small probably only means we have a bound |$\frac {dy}{dt}$| < k for some constant k. This would only practically give an upper bound |y(t)|< kT, which would be quite useless since T is quite large.